# Reversing a txt File in python

Tags: python, append, reverse

Assume you are given a file called newText.txt which contains the lines:
line 1
line 2
line 3

Write a python program that reads the data from newText.txt and writes a new file called newerText.txt in the following format:
line 3
Python Inserted a new line
line 2
line 1

I can get it reversed but the line 2 and line 3 are in the same line.
I also need help appending the new line between line 2 and line 3.
Input

```
lines = []
with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('newtext.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in reversed(lines):
        f.write(line)
```

Output

line3line2

line1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into what `text.txt` actually is, it's probably something like this:

```
line1\nline2\nline3
```

Notice how each line is divided by a new line character (`\n`). This means the last line doesn't have a new line at the end of it, so when you write it to `newText.txt`, it won't have a newline.

What you can do is strip away all possible new lines, then add one yourself:

```
with open('newtext.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in reversed(lines):
        f.write(line.strip() + "\n")
```

Comment: How would i add a new line to newtext.txt in between line 2 and line 3 that is NOT brought over from the text.txt file?

Comment: @StevenLindsey How would you know to put a line break there if the original file didn't have one?